# pyspark streaming word count example no console output

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, word-count

I want to use pyspark streaming to count words for files inside `/predix/test/` and save output in `/predix/output/`. Meanwhile the console print out the word count such as : `{hello: 5}`.

Below is the code, but console never gives output `{hello: 5}` . Can someone point out where my errors are?

Thanks.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
    sc = SparkContext(appName='streamingWordsCount', conf=conf)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)   # batch interval in seconds 5
    lines = ssc.textFileStream("/predix/test")  
    words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
    pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
    wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

    wordCounts.pprint()
    wordCounts.saveASTextFile("/predix/output")

    ssc.start()             # Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Comment: It is always advisable to use `$HOME` directory for these kinds of things instead of `/usr` which is protected directory accessible through root-access only.

Comment: @ashwinids I followed your comments and change it to my $HOME /predix. The behavior is the same,normal processing logs without error, but no word count print out either.

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375398/python-spark-streaming-example-with-textfilestream-does-not-work-why), I think you're facing the same problem.

Comment: @ashwinids the link helps, my environment is VM centos linux, it only detects new coming files from another path which are modified then saved. Simply copy/change files in the same path won't trigger the word count.   Thanks.